# How can avoid !! comparation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, boolean, comparator, boolean-logic

I am using this "!!" comparation in order to compare with "undefined". However, is there any other way to do it?

```
isWidgetTemplatesLoaded: function(widgetName) {
           return !!templates[widgetName];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: typeof templates[widgetName] !== "undefined"

Comment: `!!` will convert the value of `templates[widgetName]` to a boolean as if by `Boolean(templates[widgetName])`. How is `false == undefined` better than direct comparison as in `templates[widgetName] == undefined`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use typeof to check for undefined:

```
(typeof templates[widgetName] !== 'undefined')
```

typeof always returns a string. It returns "undefined" if the value of the variable is undefined or the variable does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `typeof` operator

```
typeof templates[widgetName];
```

else you can also use like this

```
if (templates[widgetName] === undefined) {
   // rest of code
}
else {
   // rest of code
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will that make exactly the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

To check for `undefined` you can just use the no-conversion equal/different operators:

```
if (x !== undefined) { ... }
if (y === undefined) { ... }
```

note however that this doesn't have the exact same meaning of `!!`. The double-negation for example returns `true` even for `false`, `null`, `0` or `""` despite the fact that these values are not `undefined`.

By the way in Javascript you should basically **always** use `===` and `!==` instead of `==` and `!=`, unless you really need the crazy implicit conversion that equality/different operators do (and no one needs that). Good Javascript editors will warn you about any use of `==` or `!=` as they are just bug-hiding places.

In the specific of your question code the `!!` logic seems wrong on a philosophical level because an empty template could be `""` and this function would say that the template has not been loaded while instead it has been loaded and simply happens to be the empty string.

Comment: Maybe this is because I come from Java world, but the thing that annoys me is to see that *!!*

Comment: @stackman: indeed writing code like `x !== undefined` is much better (with the only annoyance that may be someone expects you to treat `null` the same as `undefined`). Unfortunately Javascript has both `null` and `undefined` and there's no trivial way to check just for both of them because also `0` and the empty string are "falsy".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator, if you know, if the property exist with some value, other than `undefined`.

```
return widgetName in templates;
```